# Scala play framework - convert Rest API to HTTPS using .JKS file using organizational CA

Tags: scala, https, playframework, ssl-certificate, jks

Currently I am running scala play application, now it's HTTP APIs are working fine in my Angular UI application locally. But in our organization for higher environment we need to convert it to SSL HTTPS API.
We use our own organizational root CA and I got the **myCA_trust.jks** certificate file with me.

I added following properties in application.conf file,

```
play.server.https.keyStore.path="./myCA_trust.jks"
play.server.https.keyStore.password="change_me"
```

And for deploying the code I am creating the dist, and using following command to deploy it on linux server

```
./scala-rest-api -Dplay.http.secret.key="application_secreate_key" -Dhttps.port=8094 -Dplay.server.https.keyStore.path=./myCA_trust.jks -Dplay.server.https.keyStore.password=change_me
```

After doing this I can hit to the HTTPS URL using server address, but getting errors in server console like,

```
[error] a.a.OneForOneStrategy - ./myCA_trust.jks
akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: akka://application/system/StreamSupervisor-0/flow-2-1: exception during creation
        at akka.actor.ActorInitializationException$.apply(Actor.scala:202)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:698)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:549)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:571)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:293)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:228)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:241)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at play.core.server.ssl.ServerSSLEngine$.createScalaSSLEngineProvider(ServerSSLEngine.scala:116)
        at play.core.server.ssl.ServerSSLEngine$.createSSLEngineProvider(ServerSSLEngine.scala:39)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anon$4$$anon$5.sslEngineProvider$lzycompute(AkkaHttpServer.scala:527)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anon$4$$anon$5.sslEngineProvider(AkkaHttpServer.scala:526)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anon$4$$anon$5.engineCreateSSLEngine(AkkaHttpServer.scala:528)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.createSSLEngine(SSLContext.java:329)
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: ./myCA_trust.jks
```

**Please help me to configure HTTPS rest API URL, do let me know if there is anything else I need to add in the code and where.**
Thanks and in advance.

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to have Play directly handling SSL certificate, except for testing purpose, otherwise HTTP frontend/API gateway should be responsible

Comment: @cchantep It would be really helpful if you could provide any hint to convert to HTTPS, as I am checking few of the documentations but they are not helping much me to grasp from a while.

Answer (score -2):

```scala
val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
sslContext.init(null, Array[TrustManager](new X509TrustManager {
  override def checkClientTrusted(chain: Array[X509Certificate], authType: String): Unit = {}
  override def checkServerTrusted(chain: Array[X509Certificate], authType: String): Unit = {}
  override def getAcceptedIssuers: Array[X509Certificate] = null
}), new java.security.SecureRandom())
val hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier {
  override def verify(s: String, sslSession: SSLSession): Boolean = true
}
val httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext (sslContext).setSSLHostnameVerifier (hostnameVerifier).build()
val content = EntityUtils.toString(httpClient.execute(new HttpGet("https://randomuser.me/api/0.8/?results-10")).getEntity)
println(content.mkString)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**